# Navigation Drawer icons gone Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am testing the `Navigation Drawer`in **Android Studio 2.3.3**. When I create the default Navigation Drawer Activity provided by Android Studio it comes without any kind of icon in the action bar.

I have also tested in real device, launching the app right after creation, that means, without modifying anything else and the drawer does not slide in when sliding in the screen.

Anybody else faced this problem in AS 2.3.3?

Any solution for that?

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Post the xml layout of the activity

Comment: which one do you need? AS created 4: `activity_main.xml`, `app_bar_main.xml`, `content_main.xml` and `nav_header_main.xml`

Comment: activity_main.xml

Comment: there you go!!!